# Getting an error while installing 12.04 via WUBI

Tags: system-installation, windows, wubi

I am currently running Windows 7 Ultimate with a 2GB RAM and 500GB SATA HDD and a 2.60 GHZ Intel Dual Core processor. I want to use Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7. Being a complete Linux newbie, I would have preferred installation via WUBI which successfully worked for me in version 11.04.

However, the WUBI that comes with 12.04 does not allow installation in Windows, so I've tried installing by downloading the WUBI standalone installer for Windows and also by `--force-wubi`. Both approaches result in the following error:

```
Try (hd0,1): NTFS5: error : "prefix" is not set
```

I think WUBI clearly had issues with Ubuntu. Is there any way I can get rid of this error? Or is there any other distro which works with WUBI?